# what size cable is needed for 0-10v dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I recently installed 11 2x4 led panel lights in a commercial drop ceiling. The led lights are 50w 100-277v. The power wires are in a separate box on the light than the purple and gray dimmer wires. Can I use 16/2 cable and does it need to be violet and pink? Does it need to be m/c or in conduit? I will be using a separate 2 wire 0-10v dimmer switch kept away from on/off power. Also will I need all 11 home runs from light to switch or can I "daisy chain" to each light?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will the controls (wall switch, occupancy sensor, daylighting system, etc) have the 0-10v conductors separated from the mains conductors as well, or will they all be in the same junction box?

Comment: These are dimmable LED panels so what do the instructions say?

Comment: Are you running the power wires in conduit or MC?  Are you wanting to run the 0-10V alongside the power wires, or totally separately?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the 0-10V wires don't come anywhere near 120V, then common 18/2 thermostat wire should suffice and will probably be the pricing "sweet spot".  Yes, you can daisy chain, similar to how you'd wire a series of receptacles. Follow the instructions for splicing 2 or more wires to one terminal.  If you need to pigtail, the small blue wire nuts are just right for splicing 2-3 #18 wires.

Answer (score 0):

As for cables,

There are some specifically made for your application.

Romex® Brand SIMpull® NM-B-PCS Duo™ Cable – a cable that combines power conductors along with control/signal cables.

[image: cable]

or this one Southwire 16/2 Low Voltage Control and Signal Cable for 0-10V Dimming Item # Model # 64350501